# Possible to use python to script for mac?

Tags: python, macos

Is it possible to use Python in the way that AppleScript is used to automate/customize the Mac OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://appscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: appscript is deprecated...it does not work correctly under Lion.

Answer (score 2):

Since appscript is deprecated and no longer maintained, you might want to look at simply executing AppleScript directly from your python script with a popen() to /usr/bin/osascript.